# Giving different words in an <input> or <textarea> different styles using React/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In the below code I am recording the index of the text within a `<textarea>` that the user has highlighted:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  onMouseUp = e => {
    let textVal = this.refs.myTextarea;
    let cursorStart = textVal.selectionStart;
    let cursorEnd = textVal.selectionEnd;
    console.log("Highlighted text: ", textVal);
    console.log("Highlighted text index start: ", cursorStart);
    console.log("Highlighted text index end: ", cursorEnd);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <textarea ref="myTextarea" onMouseUp={e => this.onMouseUp(e)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What I would then like to do **is highlight (i.e. set a background colour for) that specific text in the text area**. But I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Does anyone have any ideas?  There appear to be some packages that will highlight specific words in the text area but none that can do it specifically by index.

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question to make it more clear now. Let me know if you have any ideas?

Comment: Apparently this isn't possible at the moment (to highlight text and apply some styles to it using CSS in  `<textarea>` or `<input>` elements). However there are [other ways](https://codersblock.com/blog/highlight-text-inside-a-textarea/) to achieve this.